# Datatablesのソースで、表示件数変更欄を生成している部分が知りたいです

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Datatablesのソースで、表示件数変更欄を生成している部分が知りたいと思い、
settings._iDisplayLengthと記載されているソースを調査していますが、見つける事が出来ていません。
分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

[DataTablesダウンロード](http://datatables.net/download/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

表示件数変更欄というのはテーブルの左上に表示される `Show [10] entries` のことでしょうか。

http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

オプション名が `lengthMenu` なので、これを `jquery.dataTables.js` 内で検索したら `_fnFeatureHtmlLength()` にたどり着きました。

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L3353

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
解決することができ、とても助かりました。